# How do you extract/where the javascript list with an array property

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I like to extract the javascript object list using underscore.js where

The original json list

```
 [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6}]
```

And the array to filter out:

> ['2','3','5']

The resulting list would be:

```
[{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":5}]
```

How can I achive this using underscore method/s and all I can think about is using the where http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a _.filter?

```
var arr = ['2', '3', '5'];

var input = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6}];

 var filtered = _.filter(input, function (obj) {
    return _.indexOf(arr, obj.id.toString()) > -1;
})
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aN6Y/)

Comment: @user1076813 if you store the arr as numbers then you can remove the .toString in the filter.